# How to correctly use google alerts API with java

Tags: java, api, google-alerts

I'm learning to work with google alerts API.
I want to create an alerts from java code, and when I have alerts put them to my DB

My way:

1. I'm able to create an new google alert , that would send alerts to my gmail.
2. Read all the mails with java from my mail.
3. I parse them and put to my DB.

**Is there a better way to do that ?** 
I saw that google can give me an XML rss , it would be much easier to parse , but I wasn't able to get the rss with java.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be helpful :

Java code to create google alert:

```
public static void addAlertToUser(String userMail , String password , String query)
    {
        GAService service;
        try {
            service = new GAService(userMail, password);
            service.doLogin();
            Alert alert = new Alert();
            alert.setSearchQuery(query);
            alert.setHowOften(HowOften.AS_IT_HAPPENS);
            //alert.setLanguage(Region.Israel);
            //alert.setLanguage(Language.Hebrew);
            alert.setHowMany(HowMany.ONLY_THE_BEST_RESULTS);
            service.createAlert(alert); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Code to read the alert from the Gmail:

```
public static void readGoogleAlretsEmail()
{
    Hashtable<String , Alert[]> allAlerts = checkMail("myGmail@gmail.com", "12q3wa4esz");
    for(String key : allAlerts.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println("Key : " + key + "\n");
        Alert[] alerts = allAlerts.get(key);
        for (int i = 0; i < alerts.length; i++) 
        {
            Alert currentAlret = (Alert)alerts[i];
            System.out.println(i + ". " + alerts[i]);
            TextAnalysisResults results = TextAnalysis.getResults(currentAlret.title,currentAlret.content);
        }
    }
}
```